# Why MySQL imports only one record for each table?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, ubuntu

Code shows some info:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release | grep VERSION
6:VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

$ mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME > dump.sql

$ ll dump.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 root    397M Dec 29 01:13 dump.sql

$ mysql -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME < dump.sql
```

MySQL don't show any errors but after import i have only first rows in all tables.
I've checked with head sql syntax and it seems to be correct.

I've tried also `mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME | gzip -9 > dump.sql.gz` and got same situation.

Why this is happening?
And how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: You sure your queries don't have LIMIT 1 or something in them? Maybe you could show the first few lines of a .sql file?

Comment: `$ fgrep LIMIT dump.sql` returns no rows.

Comment: Sure, here is output of `$ head -50 dump.sql`: https://gist.github.com/TrogWarZ/34bb292c38e2916350cb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Mac OS (10.10.1) and SequelPro (1.0.2).

This is bug in SequelPro, i think: bug began to appear after upgrading OS to 10.10.1.

See [issue #2048](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2048) on GitHub.